# Acceder a un template a través de un modal con django

Tags: django, template

Hola comunidad estoy intentando registrar un usuario a través de un modal, el cual lo llamo desde un botón, este botón está disponible en 3 templates más, el problema es que si intento registrar un usuario sin estar en el témplate correspondiente en este caso register.html se recarga la página me redirecciona, pero desaparece el modal, he consultado la manera de hacerlo y aún no lo logro, alguien que me pueda ayudar por favor.

Comment: Puedes compartir lo que tienes realizado hasta el momento?

Comment: Mira, desde este botón llamo el modal.

Comment: <a href="{% url 'barber:register' %}" class="topbar__icon" data-type="register" 
          title="Register">
          <p class="btn btn-right">Sign up </p>
        </a>

Comment: La idea es desde allí llamar al modal y a su vez la view para registrar el usuario.

Comment: Se lo que tratas de hacer, yo lo intente con un formulario para cambiar los valores de un modelo, este formulario tenia que estar en todas las vistas. Yo al final decidí  hacer una vista y llamarla a través de JavaScript. Otra opción que puedes hacer es crear un, template mixing que se use en todas las vistas que quieras poner el registro.

Comment: Entiendo, y como haces para que cargarlo desde JavaScript, lo intente muchas veces y como ese botón es una etiqueta <a></a>, recarga la página si me redirecciona, pero el modal no permanece en el, template.